# how to save multiple selected buttons in custom cell?

Tags: ios, uitableview, custom-cell

in my custom cell lot of question and answers are there, in each section i want to select any one button,that button how can store it? in CellForRowAtIndexPath i created targets for each answer,
here is my code!

```
-(void)buttonsClicked:(id)sender
 {
    UIButton *btn=(UIButton*)sender;

    ContestQATableViewCell * cell=(ContestQATableViewCell *)[btn.superview superview];
    if (cell.answer1.tag==btn.tag)
    {
        NSLog(@"%ld",(long)btn.tag);
        [cell.answer1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"RadioChecked"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }else{

        [cell.answer1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"RadioUnChecked"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    if (cell.answer2.tag==btn.tag)
    {
        NSLog(@"%ld",(long)btn.tag);
        [cell.answer2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"RadioChecked"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }else{

        [cell.answer2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"RadioUnChecked"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    if (cell.answer3.tag==btn.tag)
    {
        NSLog(@"%ld",(long)btn.tag);
        [cell.answer3 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"RadioChecked"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }else{

        [cell.answer3 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"RadioUnChecked"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    if (cell.answer4.tag==btn.tag)
    {
        NSLog(@"%ld",(long)btn.tag);
        [cell.answer4 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"RadioChecked"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }else{

        [cell.answer4 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"RadioUnChecked"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
 }
```

Comment: You need to store the reference of the button you selected or a flag somewhere in an array .

Comment: you can store every information you need on your _model-layer_, then when the cell need to redraw, you can recall the information from that.

Answer (score 4):

You need add one key your datasource array and modify that key value depend upon button state on click action. Check below code for your reference

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
        MyCustomTableViewCell *cell = (MyCustomTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyCustomTableViewCell"];
        [cell.btnSelect addTarget:self action:@selector(btnSelectClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        cell.btnSelect.selected = [[[self.arraySource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"isSleected"] boolValue];
        cell.btnSelect.tag = indexPath.row;
        return cell;
    }
    - (void)btnSelectClick:(UIButton *)sender {
        sender.selected = !sender.selected;
        NSMutableDictionary *dicTemp = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:[self.arraySource objectAtIndex:sender.tag]];
        [dicTemp setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:sender.selected] forKey:@"isSleected"];
        [self.arraySource replaceObjectAtIndex:sender.tag withObject:dicTemp];
    }

  Here is arraySource in view did load
  self.arraySource = [NSMutableArray array];
  [self.arraySource addObject:@{@"name":@"name-1"}];
  [self.arraySource addObject:@{@"name":@"name-2"}];
  [self.arraySource addObject:@{@"name":@"name-3"}];
```